# Return text within the same cell if value is less than zero

Tags: excel

Is it possible to return a text value within the same cell if a cells formula result is less than zero..

I have a formula =A2+B2, if the result is positive then display result , if negative then "No Bonus" ..

Comment: To show a complete different way, just set the cell format to something like `0.00;"No Bonus";0.00;@` ;)

Comment: That's pretty creative!  What does each part mean? Or where can I trigger say "greater than"??

Comment: the parts are separated by the `;` while the first part is for positive numbers, the second for negative, the third for 0 and the forth for text. but that is because my way has no "trigger"... to show "No Bunus" only numbers smaller or even to 12.7 and bigger than 3, you can use `[>12.7]0.00;[>=3]"No Bonus";0.00`... there are lots of ways to use this. [THIS](http://simoncpage.co.uk/blog/2008/09/excel-custom-and-conditional-number-formatting/) may be helpful ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel - (...2+ years later...) - WOAH! I didn't know you could do 'conditional formatting' with the cell format.  I've spent the past 30ish minutes digging around online and that is an awesome feature I had no idea about!  Unfortunately your link seems to be dead - any chance it's available elsewhere? (I'd link to the Archive.org backup, but their search is down right now).

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry for the late reply... was just one site like many others... check [THIS](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/) or pick one from [HERE](https://www.google.de/search?q=excel+custom+number+format) ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel -...no need to apologize on my reply on a post over two years ago! Thanks for the links :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use an `If()` formula.

Say the cell with the formula `=A2+B2` is `C1`, you can do this:

`=If(C1>=0,C1,"No Bonus")`

Or without the `C1` cell: `=If((A2+B2)>=0,A2+B2,"No Bonus")`

Note that if the employee gets `0`, that's included as a "positive".

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it Batman, I was on that same route but the MOndays got me!